# Read integers and strings from a single line of a console

Tags: java, console, java.util.scanner

The problem is like this:

**I have two programs which takes input from a console but in different manner:** 
**1)**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int temp1 = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    String str = input.nextLine();
    int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(str);
    int total = temp1+temp2;

    System.out.println(total);
```

**2)**

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int temp1 = input.nextInt();
 // input.nextLine();
    String str = input.nextLine();
    int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(str);
    int total = temp1+temp2;

    System.out.println(total);
```

In 1st case 1 take inputs in 2 different lines like

```
1
2
```

so it gives correct answer but in 2nd case I removed the `input.nextLine()` statement to take inputs in a single line like:

```
1 2
```

it gives me number format exception why?? and also suggest me how I can read integers and strings from a single line of a console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `str` has the value `" 2"`, and the leading space is not legal syntax for `parseInt()`. You need to either skip the white space between the two numbers in the input or trim the white space off of `str` before parsing as an `int`. To skip white space, do this:

```
input.skip("\\s*");
String str = input.nextLine();
```

To trim the space off of `str` before parsing, do this:

```
int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
```

You can also get fancy and read the two pieces of the line in one go:

```
if (input.findInLine("(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)") == null) {
    // expected pattern was not found
    System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
} else {
    // expected pattern was found - retrieve and parse the pieces
    MatchResult result = input.match();
    int temp1 = Integer.parseInt(result.group(1));
    int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(result.group(2));
    int total = temp1+temp2;

    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is `1 2`, after this line

```
String str = input.nextLine();
```

`str` is equal to `" 2"`, so it can't be parsed as int.

You can do simply:

```
int temp1 = input.nextInt();
int temp2 = input.nextInt();
int total = temp1+temp2;
System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: Yes but what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: The solution is input.skip("\\s*"); because in the cases where we need real strings like "abc" then your solution is not sufficient.

Comment: @pushpendra It wasn't obvious from your question that you have numbers and strings intermixed.

Answer (score 0):

in your next line there is no integer ... its trying to create and integer from null ... hence you get number formate exception. If you use split string on temp1 then you get 2 string with values 1 and 2.