# how to ranking of race time

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I need to write a program that can ranking race time of 10 runners
so I created 2 arrays

1. ID of runners (10 runners)
2. race time of 10 runners (race time must be less than or equal to 20.0 sec)

and I found that my sorting algorithm can't be used correctly, I don't want to use `Arrays.sort(x);` because I need to sort "those race time and ID" here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] ID = new String[10];
        double[] time = new double[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < ID.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter ID and times: ");
            ID[i] = sc.nextLine();
            time[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        }

        Run a = new Run(ID, time);
        System.out.println("Top 3 is ");
        a.Sort();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Run {
    private String[] ID = new String[10];
    private double[] time = new double[10];
    public Run(String[] ID, double[] time) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ID.length; i++) {
            this.ID[i] = ID[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
            if (time[i] <= 20.0) {
                this.time[i] = time[i];
            }
        }
    }
    public void Sort() {
        double tem1;
        String tem2;

        for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < time.length; j++) {
                if (time[j] > time[j+1]) {
                    tem1 = time[j];
                    time[j] = time[j+1];
                    time[j+1] = tem1;
                    tem2 = ID[j];
                    ID[j] = ID[j+1];
                    ID[j+1] = tem2;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(ID[i] + " " + time[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

so I need to know why my sorting algorithm can't be used correctly, it's pop an error on my console.

One more question, in the input stage when I input first ID and time, if I press like this

ID[0] -> Enter -> time[0]

then the input is correct but if I press

ID[0] -> Spacebar -> time[0]

then the input is wrong.
Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you allowed to use [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) as they are made for your question? If yes, I can post an answer explaining that

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is that you are passing an array of 10 elements in the constructor of `Run`; this is not necessary, you can directly pass the arrays:

In main:

```
Run a = new Run(ID, time);
```

In run:

```
public Run(String[] ID, double[] time) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.time = time;
}
```

Can you post the error log?

Read here for the problem in reading the inputs: [Read integers and strings from a single line of a console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646835/read-integers-and-strings-from-a-single-line-of-a-console)

The problem is that you are trying to get in an array cell that doesn't exist: `array.length` returns the length of the array, so in that case returns 10.

You are doing a for cycle from 0 to 10, then you are trying to get (in the if statement) inside `time[11]` (it was `time[j+1]`).

Change the for cycle to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < time.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < time.length - 1; j++) {
            System.out.println(i + " "+ j);
            if (time[j] > time[j+1]) {
                tem1 = time[j];
                time[j] = time[j+1];
                time[j+1] = tem1;
                tem2 = ID[j];
                ID[j] = ID[j+1];
                ID[j+1] = tem2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pleasant94 answered your question regarding the index error.
To answer your question about why you need to enter a new line (press enter) after inputting the ID is because you are scanning the whole line into the ID value using `nextLine()`. Instead of using `nextInt()` like you did for time with `nextDouble()`.

like so:

```
    ...
    ID[i] = sc.nextInt();
    time[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    ...
```

Check out the Java docs for the scanner class here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

And because you are now scanning in a int you'll have to update all your ID variables to int. Combining it with Pleasant94's answer you should be able to do just do this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] ID = new int[10];
        double[] time = new double[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < ID.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter ID and times: ");
            ID[i] = sc.nextInt();
            time[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        }

        Run a = new Run(ID, time);
        System.out.println("Top 3 is ");
        a.Sort();
    }

}

class Run {
    private int[] ID = new int[10];
    private double[] time = new double[10];
    public Run(int[] ID, double[] time) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ID.length; i++) {
            this.ID[i] = ID[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
            if (time[i] <= 20.0) {
                this.time[i] = time[i];
            }
        }
    }
    public void Sort() {
        double tem1;
        int tem2;

        for (int i = 0; i < time.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < time.length - 1; j++) {
                if (time[j] > time[j+1]) {
                    tem1 = time[j];
                    time[j] = time[j+1];
                    time[j+1] = tem1;
                    tem2 = ID[j];
                    ID[j] = ID[j+1];
                    ID[j+1] = tem2;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(ID[i] + " " + time[i]);
        }
    }
}
```